# Django module not defined upon syncing alternative DB

Tags: python, database, django

I'm trying to add an alternative database to my Django project.

I edited `settings.py` thusly:

```
'bonds': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
    'NAME': '/var/www/tbg/database/bonds.db',
    'USER': '',
    'PASSWORD': '',
    'HOST': '',
    'PORT': '',
    }
```

inside the `DATABASES` variable.

Now what's strange is that, when I run `python manage.py syncdb --database=bonds`, I get an error

```
sendfile is not defined
```

I have the variable `SENDFILE_BACKEND = sendfile.backends.simple` for unrelated usage. The sendfile module worked perfectly before I installed the alternative database.

Docs for sendfile: https://github.com/johnsensible/django-sendfile

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for wasting your time, lads. The answer is that I had recovered an earlier version of the file, which had no quotation marks around the `SENDFILE_BACKEND` variable. It should be

```
SENDFILE_BACKEND = 'sendfile.backends.simple'
```